# Which is better Axel or Aria 2

Tags: download-manager

Hey guys I am new to linux and I want to know that which downloader is better for utilizing the full download bandwidth 
??

Comment: I doubt either of them can do anything about the download speed your browser doesn't do already.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Most web browsers do not, at least without installing a download acceleration extension, automatically perform multiple downloads for the same file (either from different servers or the same server) simultaneously.

Comment: @EliahKagan: You're right. I totally forgot that, because I didn't have to use multi-segment downloads in years despite a fast internet connection.

Comment: @AvishekSaha If you still want an(other) answer to this, or otherwise  want it reopened, I recommend you [edit] it to be more specific about your needs and also to ask something like "What are the considerations in deciding..." Such a phrase doesn't automatically make a question sufficiently objective to be suitable, but it might help indicate you're looking for substantial answers that rely on facts and serve to help you make the decision for yourself. (*If* that's what you're looking for.) I would consider voting to reopen this question if it were edited, and I suspect others might too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aria2 is better than Axel and also with Aria2 you can combine Aria2 with uGet and get a very nice GUI for Aria2.

Comment: The developer of apt-fast agrees with you. Apt-fast used to use the axel program in Ubuntu 2012, but now it uses aria2.